# Uninitialized static final field in disassembly

Tags: android, smali

How can it be? R$styleable.smali :

```
...
# static fields
.field public static final CallForwardEditPreference:[I = null
.field public static final CallForwardEditPreference_reason:I = 0x1
.field public static final CallForwardEditPreference_serviceClass:I = 0x0
.field public static final EditPhoneNumberPreference:[I = null
.field public static final EditPhoneNumberPreference_changeNumButtonText:I = 0x2
.field public static final EditPhoneNumberPreference_confirmMode:I = 0x3
.field public static final EditPhoneNumberPreference_disableButtonText:I = 0x1

.field public static final EditPhoneNumberPreference_enableButtonText:I

# direct methods
...
```

and no other occurrences of `EditPhoneNumberPreference_enableButtonText` in this or other files

Answer (score 1):

Uninitialized fields are actually initialized to the default null/0 value for that type.